# Parameter Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters

So I've defined a function called `change(a,d)` that computes the change of amount a given denominations d. I've also got some parameters: a must be of type int, d must be of type list of int, and the elements of d must be in ascending order, otherwise ChangeParameterError is raised. My code is as follows:

```
class ChangeRemainderError(Exception):
   pass

class ChangeParameterError(Exception):
   pass

def change(a, d):
    if type(a) != int:
      raise ChangeParameterError
    if type(d) != type(list):
      raise ChangeParameterError
    if type(d) != d.sort():
      raise ChangeParameterError

   i, r, c = len(d)-1, a, len(d)*[0]
   while i >= 0:
     c[i], r = divmod(r, d[i])
     i = i-1
   return c
def printChange(a, d):
    try:
        print(change(a, d))
    except ChangeParameterError:
        print('needs an integer amount and a non-empty list \
of denominations in ascending order')
    except ChangeRemainderError:
        print('no exact change possible')
    except:
        print('unexpected error')
```

and as it stands it's throw ChangeParameterError for tests it shouldn't be doing so. For example:
`change(3, [3, 7]) ==  [1, 0]`

returns the ChangeParameterError even though a is an int and d is a list in ascending order. And the error message isn't really helpful. The error message is as follows:

```
<ipython-input-39-62477b9defff> in change(a, d)
     19         raise ChangeParameterError
     20     if type(d) != type(list):
---> 21         raise ChangeParameterError
     22     if type(d) != d.sort():
     23         raise ChangeParameterError

ChangeParameterError:
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please show the rest of the error message. In fact, the bottom part of it is the most important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two logic errors that I can see. Try this instead:

```
def change(a, d):
    if type(a) != int:
      raise ChangeParameterError
    if type(d) != list:  # 1
      raise ChangeParameterError
    if d != sorted(d):  # 2
      raise ChangeParameterError
```

First, `type(list)` is going to return the type `<type>`.

Second,  you included `type(d)` in your third check where it doesn't make sense. Also, `d.sort()` doesn't return anything; it sorts the list in place.

Also, it's better to use `isinstance` rather than checking the return value of `type`.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jonathon! That did in fact solve `change(3, [3, 7]) ==  [1, 0]`. But now `change(3, [2,7])` which is supposed to raise the aforementioned error, is now just returning `[1,0]` hahahha.

Comment: I don't understand why that should raise an error. First argument is int, second is list, list is sorted.

Comment: Oops, sorry I also have a 'ChangeRemainderError', I was confused whilst replying to you! thanks!